# when i build the sonar stage i got below error

Tags: sonarqube

**i'm using below command**

```
/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/Sonarqube_scanner/bin/sonar-scanner  -Dproject.settings=sonar-project.properties
```

**i got below error**

> ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
> org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: Please provide compiled classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries property
>
> ERROR:
> ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

Comment: As explained in the message, you should have your Java project compiled first. The analyzer needs to know where your compiled classes are. When building with Maven or Gradle using SonarQube plugin, it should be detected automatically, otherwise you need to specify output location with _sonar.java.binaries_ property.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.